# Return root ownership to /usr

Tags: sudo, chown

I stupidly ran this command in Ubuntu 18.04:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /usr
```

Now I want to undo this but when I run:

```
chown -R root:root /usr
```

I get this error:

```
operation not permitted
```

And I can't run a sudo command and gives me this error:

```
/usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and setuid bit set
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Reboot in [recovery mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode).

Comment: @Kulfy The accepted answer to that question suggests to completely reinstall Ubuntu, which is overkill.

Comment: Iam facing a deadline isn't any other way except reinstalling?

Comment: @Jos In what way is the accepted answer "overkill"? I checked and there are 13 different `[UID,GID]` pairs on my `/usr`.

Comment: @waltinator Hm. All four of my systems have only `/usr/bin/at` as the exception (daemon:daemon). But I realize I simply assumed that the whole of `/usr` was owned by root.

Comment: @Jos It's difficult to determine and replicate the original schema, I think.

Answer (score 2):

You have to boot in maintenance (recovery) mode or with live CD / USB and mount the root volume.

Comment: Can you give more details of how to fix this in recovery mode?

Comment: See the link I provided. After step 9, enter your `chown -R root:root /usr` and reboot.

Comment: That won't fix the files owned by `root`, but in one of the `cricket`, `crontab`, `dip`, `mail`, `messagebus`, `mlocate`, `postdrop`, `shadow`, `ssh`, `tty` or `utmp` groups. Many strange failures are in your future.